# Does class that inherits from abstract class that implements interface also implement that interface?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public abstract class WHAT : IInterface
{
 ...
}


public class SOWHAT : WHAT
{
 ...
}
```

It looks like its is doing this but wanted to verify this is correct to do this, Can I simply pass the SOWHAT object to a method that expects a type IInterface?

(i.e. will SOWHAT class also be of type IInterface)

Comment: The easiest way to figure something like this out is to try it. You only need a few more lines of code. And... yes & yes. These are basic traits of OOP polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

`SOWHAT` is also a child of `IInterface`. "Can I simply pass the SOWHAT object to a method that expects a type IInterface?" This is perfectly fine and you can definitely do this.

I highly recommend you read up on [**Polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Here is a class diagram that should put things in perspective:

[image]